# make a nameless array out 2 diferent tables with children in php

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, resultset

I have 2 tables in my DB. 1 is full with numbers (foreign keys) and other one is full of the data I need. This is how the array should (exactly) look

```
"array" : [
    {
        "data" : "blabla"
        "data2" : "blabla"
        "children" : [
            {
                "data" : "blabla"
                "data2" : "blabla" 
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "data" : "blabla"
                        "data2" : "blabla" 
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "data" : "blabla"
                "data2" : "blabla" 
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "data" : "blabla"
                        "data2" : "blabla" 
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

and so on, so to say.. now the right order you can find in table 1,where it is lited what the mother ID is. and i need to get the data out of table 2 so be in the array. anyone knows how to do this? i am working in codeigniter

updated with pics:

[image]

[image]

Comment: wanted to add that in theory, the amount of childs could be/should be endless

Comment: Can you post the structure of your two tables in a more direct manner ? It would help greatly.

Comment: added pictures to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you would need to process in two steps:

1. You fetch each document and it's data from the two tables (let's call them "documents" and "documents_data" to build a flat array of all the documents. This way you don't have to wonder where does the data go anymore :

   ```
   $results = $this->db->query("SELECT d.*, dd.* FROM documents d LEFT JOIN documents_data dd ON dd.doc_id = d.doc_id");
   $documents = $results->result_array();
   ```
2. Now that we have everything about each document, we just need to reorder them in a recursive array using a recursive function, that will call itself with the parent id for each children and build the tree :

   ```
   function getDocumentTree($documents, $idParent = null)
   {
       $tree = [];

       foreach($documents as $document) {
           if($document['doc_doc_id'] == $idParent) {
               $document['children'] = getDocumentTree($documents, $document['doc_id']);
               $tree[] = $document;
           }
       }

       return $tree;
   }

   $tree = getDocumentTree($documents);
   ```

Note: I haven't tested this code, this is just an idea on how it works, try to understand that (especially the concept of recursivity) and implement it by yourself.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will try this out right away

Comment: hey, i tried out your code. i gotten the following error

Comment: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!

Comment: should add that i did dit it according to my own data

Comment: This denotes an infinite recursion. I just tested my code on a flat array of data, and it works as expected. Are you using it on massive amount of recursive data ? If not, maybe try to check what the first part (fetching the elements from the database) returns as array and try to work out the tree structure yourself, maybe there's a cyclical reference in the documents (which is something that can happen).

Comment: yeah, the table has over 150 rows,  and supposivly increasing

Comment: i fixed it based on your code, but changin ithere and there. and also changing the query to the DB

Comment: Nice, I hope you understood how it works, that's the essential.